# How to do Product Collection print_r In category List page For Configurable Product?

Tags: magento2

How to do Product Collection  print_r In category List page  For Configurable Product ?

i want to check all attributes for products  single Products ?

Comment: If you have any issue then feel free to ask

Comment: Is it useful or not? @VinaySingh